# Disable mouse movment wakeup but there is no power management tab in device manager for the HID compliant mouse

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, sleep, wake-up

I am able to wakeup my sleeping computer by moving the mouse.

How do I disable that?

(I am not going to turn the mouse off manually every time I sleep the computer or disconnect it or try to have it in place where it will not move).

I only want to wake the computer with the keyboard so I tried to disable mouse wakeup.

According to https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/stop-mouse-from-waking-windows-up-from-sleep-mode/ you do that with device manager, select the HID compliant mouse and go to the power management tab and uncheck "Allow the device to wake the computer"

But there is no power management tab.

According to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/power-management-tab-is-missing-from-device/0a3c563a-5ec7-4809-9609-4bc257444590 I can make the power management tab visible by editing the registry key

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power`

and add the DWORD value `CsEnabled` that should be set to `0` and restart.

There is still no power management tab on my HID compliant mice in device manager.

[image]

In an elevated `cmd.exe`

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>powercfg /devicequery wake_armed
NONE

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /lastwake
Wake History Count - 0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: If there is no internal power management for the mouse, you will need to turn the mouse off. That will work.

Comment: Editing question to specify that I do not want to turn the mouse off every time I sleep the computer.

Comment: Put the mouse somewhere where it will not move. Then it will not wake up the computer. I do this and it works fine.

Comment: Editing question to specify that I will not keep it from moving.

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd.exe` elevated and input...

`powercfg /devicequery wake_armed`

...then...

`powercfg /devicedisablewake "DEVICE-NAME"` (note: replace "DEVICE-NAME", including quotes)

...confirm device is no longer listed in...

`powercfg /devicequery wake_armed`

Comment: Only outputting NONE, updating question.

Comment: Try `powercfg/lastwake`?  What does it say?

Comment: Adding `powercfg /lastwake` output (that seems to not be to my advantage) to the question.